# How to pass Puma::Configuration to Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, puma

This is my web app:

```
class Front < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :server, :puma
  end
  get '/' do
    'Hello, world!'
  end 
end
```

I start it like this (don't suggest to use Rack, please):

```
Front.start!
```

Here is my configuration object for Puma, which I don't know how to pass to it:

```
require 'puma/configuration'
Puma::Configuration.new({ log_requests: true, debug: true })
```

Seriously, how?

Comment: I don't suggest to use Rack, because you already use it.

Comment: I just will try to guess. You have ran Puma with Sinatra somehow and need to configure Puma. Ok, use `-c path` CLI option OR `config/puma.rb` file https://github.com/puma/puma#configuration

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I don't run Puma/Sinatra from command line, that's the thing. I run it from another Ruby context, just by using `Front.start!`. So, there is no command line. I just need to pass the configuration object to Puma.

Comment: Did you try `config/puma.rb` ? If you need dynamic config, @user2795430 answer looks good.

Comment: And a good question: _why_ do you run it not from cmd?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk check it out: https://github.com/zold-io/zold/blob/0.15.0/lib/zold/commands/node.rb#L250

Comment: Omg, did you use some Java->Ruby code translator ? :D

Comment: Seriously, I believe it could be redesigned into cli-first. Based on your code looks like java, Slop instead of Thor, etc, I think you didn't dedicated enough time to watch present framework sources. IMHO, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configuration is tightly connected to a way in which you run `puma` server.

The standard way to run `puma` - `puma` CLI command. In order to configure `puma` config file `config/puma.rb` or `config/puma/<environment>.rb` should be provided (see [example](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/examples/config.rb)).

But you asked how to pass `Puma::Configuration` object to `puma`. I wonder why you need it but AFAIK you need to run `puma` server programmatically in your application code with `Puma::Launcher`(see [source code](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/launcher.rb#L39))

```
conf = Puma::Configuration.new do |user_config|
  user_config.threads 1, 10
  user_config.app do |env|
    [200, {}, ["hello world"]]
  end
 end
Puma::Launcher.new(conf, events: Puma::Events.stdio).run
```

`user_config.app` may be any callable object (compatible with `Rack` interface) like Sinatra application.

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to pass exactly an object or just a configuration in general? For the last option it's possible, but Puma will not log anything anyway (I'm not sure, but seems like you worry exactly about logging settings for Puma).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile(true) do
  gem 'sinatra'
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'openssl'
end

require 'sinatra/base'

class Front < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :server, :puma
    set :server_settings, log_requests: true, debug: true, environment: 'foo'
  end

  get '/' do
    'Hello, world!'
  end
end

Front.start!
```

Comment: Yes, because Puma expects `config.ru` file to be. If I were you, I would look for another way. What do you want in general? To log your request or to log request exactly by Puma? I think the first is possible, but not sure about the last.

Comment: I want to have the ability to configure the server. The logging part is just an example, there are many other configuration parameters, which I need to twist.

Comment: You've already got a solution in mind (pass a config object) for the actual problem, but you haven't said what the actual problem is.  That's not how this works.  Tell us the actual problem and let us come up with the solution.